# How to create a rounded corner hexagon?

Tags: android, android-layout, svg

i want create a hexagon with rounded corners in android XML. i don't want java code.i want to set hexagon as a background of text view.  please help me. thank you in advance.this vector image currently using

```
<vector android:height="24dp" android:viewportHeight="628.0"
    android:viewportWidth="726.0"
    android:width="27dp"

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<path android:fillColor="#00ffffff"

      android:pathData="m723,314c-60,103.9 -120,207.8 -180,311.8 -120,0 -240,0 -360,0C123,521.8 63,417.9 3,314 63,210.1 123,106.2 183,2.2c120,0 240,0 360,0C603,106.2 663,210.1 723,314Z"
      android:strokeColor="#008000" android:strokeWidth="25"
/>
```

Comment: do you have SVG of the design?

Comment: like this         https://medium.com/gravitdesigner/design-a-professional-logo-using-gravit-835408f7fd9d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also use as below

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24">

    <path
        android:fillColor="#20be86"
        android:strokeWidth="1"
        android:pathData="M10.86 1.02C11.43 0.7 12.13 0.7 12.71 1.02C13.54 1.49 20.24 5.26 21.08 5.73C21.65 6.05 22 6.65 22 7.29C22 8.23 22 15.77 22 16.71C22 17.35 21.65 17.95 21.08 18.27C20.24 18.74 13.54 22.51 12.71 22.98C12.13 23.3 11.43 23.3 10.86 22.98C10.02 22.51 3.32 18.74 2.49 18.27C1.92 17.95 1.56 17.35 1.56 16.71C1.56 15.77 1.56 8.23 1.56 7.29C1.56 6.65 1.92 6.05 2.49 5.73" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#000000"
        android:fillAlpha="0"
        android:strokeColor="#000000"
        android:strokeAlpha="0"
        android:strokeWidth="1"
        android:pathData="M10.86 1.02C11.43 0.7 12.13 0.7 12.71 1.02C13.54 1.49 20.24 5.26 21.08 5.73C21.65 6.05 22 6.65 22 7.29C22 8.23 22 15.77 22 16.71C22 17.35 21.65 17.95 21.08 18.27C20.24 18.74 13.54 22.51 12.71 22.98C12.13 23.3 11.43 23.3 10.86 22.98C10.02 22.51 3.32 18.74 2.49 18.27C1.92 17.95 1.56 17.35 1.56 16.71C1.56 15.77 1.56 8.23 1.56 7.29C1.56 6.65 1.92 6.05 2.49 5.73" />
    <path
        android:fillColor="#20be86"
        android:fillAlpha="0"
        android:strokeColor="#000000"
        android:strokeAlpha="0"
        android:strokeWidth="1"
        android:pathData="M10.86 1.02C11.43 0.7 12.13 0.7 12.71 1.02C13.54 1.49 20.24 5.26 21.08 5.73C21.65 6.05 22 6.65 22 7.29C22 8.23 22 15.77 22 16.71C22 17.35 21.65 17.95 21.08 18.27C20.24 18.74 13.54 22.51 12.71 22.98C12.13 23.3 11.43 23.3 10.86 22.98C10.02 22.51 3.32 18.74 2.49 18.27C1.92 17.95 1.56 17.35 1.56 16.71C1.56 15.77 1.56 8.23 1.56 7.29C1.56 6.65 1.92 6.05 2.49 5.73" />
</vector>
```

**UPDATE**: rotate with corner

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="24dp"
android:height="24dp"
android:viewportWidth="24"
android:viewportHeight="24">

<path
    android:fillColor="#20be86"
    android:strokeWidth="1"
    android:pathData="M22.75 10.95C23.08 11.52 23.08 12.22 22.77 12.8C22.31 13.64 18.62 20.38 18.16 21.23C17.85 21.8 17.25 22.16 16.61 22.16C15.67 22.18 8.13 22.26 7.19 22.27C6.55 22.28 5.95 21.94 5.62 21.37C5.14 20.54 1.29 13.88 0.81 13.06C0.48 12.48 0.48 11.78 0.79 11.21C1.25 10.36 4.94 3.62 5.4 2.78C5.71 2.21 6.31 1.84 6.95 1.84C7.89 1.82 15.43 1.74 16.37 1.73C17.01 1.72 17.61 2.07 17.94 2.64" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#000000"
    android:fillAlpha="0"
    android:strokeColor="#000000"
    android:strokeAlpha="0"
    android:strokeWidth="1"
    android:pathData="M22.75 10.95C23.08 11.52 23.08 12.22 22.77 12.8C22.31 13.64 18.62 20.38 18.16 21.23C17.85 21.8 17.25 22.16 16.61 22.16C15.67 22.18 8.13 22.26 7.19 22.27C6.55 22.28 5.95 21.94 5.62 21.37C5.14 20.54 1.29 13.88 0.81 13.06C0.48 12.48 0.48 11.78 0.79 11.21C1.25 10.36 4.94 3.62 5.4 2.78C5.71 2.21 6.31 1.84 6.95 1.84C7.89 1.82 15.43 1.74 16.37 1.73C17.01 1.72 17.61 2.07 17.94 2.64" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#20be86"
    android:fillAlpha="0"
    android:strokeColor="#000000"
    android:strokeAlpha="0"
    android:strokeWidth="1"
    android:pathData="M22.75 10.95C23.08 11.52 23.08 12.22 22.77 12.8C22.31 13.64 18.62 20.38 18.16 21.23C17.85 21.8 17.25 22.16 16.61 22.16C15.67 22.18 8.13 22.26 7.19 22.27C6.55 22.28 5.95 21.94 5.62 21.37C5.14 20.54 1.29 13.88 0.81 13.06C0.48 12.48 0.48 11.78 0.79 11.21C1.25 10.36 4.94 3.62 5.4 2.78C5.71 2.21 6.31 1.84 6.95 1.84C7.89 1.82 15.43 1.74 16.37 1.73C17.01 1.72 17.61 2.07 17.94 2.64" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#000000"
    android:fillAlpha="0"
    android:strokeWidth="1"
    android:pathData="M22.75 10.95C23.08 11.52 23.08 12.22 22.77 12.8C22.31 13.64 18.62 20.38 18.16 21.23C17.85 21.8 17.25 22.16 16.61 22.16C15.67 22.18 8.13 22.26 7.19 22.27C6.55 22.28 5.95 21.94 5.62 21.37C5.14 20.54 1.29 13.88 0.81 13.06C0.48 12.48 0.48 11.78 0.79 11.21C1.25 10.36 4.94 3.62 5.4 2.78C5.71 2.21 6.31 1.84 6.95 1.84C7.89 1.82 15.43 1.74 16.37 1.73C17.01 1.72 17.61 2.07 17.94 2.64" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#000000"
    android:fillAlpha="0"
    android:strokeColor="#000000"
    android:strokeAlpha="0"
    android:strokeWidth="1"
    android:pathData="M22.75 10.95C23.08 11.52 23.08 12.22 22.77 12.8C22.31 13.64 18.62 20.38 18.16 21.23C17.85 21.8 17.25 22.16 16.61 22.16C15.67 22.18 8.13 22.26 7.19 22.27C6.55 22.28 5.95 21.94 5.62 21.37C5.14 20.54 1.29 13.88 0.81 13.06C0.48 12.48 0.48 11.78 0.79 11.21C1.25 10.36 4.94 3.62 5.4 2.78C5.71 2.21 6.31 1.84 6.95 1.84C7.89 1.82 15.43 1.74 16.37 1.73C17.01 1.72 17.61 2.07 17.94 2.64" />
<path
    android:fillColor="#000000"
    android:fillAlpha="0"
    android:strokeColor="#000000"
    android:strokeAlpha="0"
    android:strokeWidth="1"
    android:pathData="M22.75 10.95C23.08 11.52 23.08 12.22 22.77 12.8C22.31 13.64 18.62 20.38 18.16 21.23C17.85 21.8 17.25 22.16 16.61 22.16C15.67 22.18 8.13 22.26 7.19 22.27C6.55 22.28 5.95 21.94 5.62 21.37C5.14 20.54 1.29 13.88 0.81 13.06C0.48 12.48 0.48 11.78 0.79 11.21C1.25 10.36 4.94 3.62 5.4 2.78C5.71 2.21 6.31 1.84 6.95 1.84C7.89 1.82 15.43 1.74 16.37 1.73C17.01 1.72 17.61 2.07 17.94 2.64" />
```

**Stroke color added, and  fill color transparent**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:width="225.000000dp"
android:height="225.000000dp"
android:viewportWidth="225.000000"
android:viewportHeight="225.000000">

<group
    android:translateY="225.000000"
    android:scaleX="0.100000"
    android:scaleY="-0.100000">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#000000"
        android:strokeWidth="1"
        android:pathData="M560 2143 c-17 -17 -132 -218 -281 -493 -220 -405 -253 -471 -253 -510 -1 -40 17 -78 153 -330 346 -637 355 -654 391 -678 l34 -23 528 3 528 3 34 35 c42 43 504 892 517 950 6 27 6 55 -2 83 -6 22 -119 241 -252 486 -207 380 -248 448 -281 473 l-39 28 -523 0 -524 0 -30 -27z m1072 -90 c31 -38 488 -893 488 -915 0 -32 -454 -867 -490 -900 -20 -19 -44 -28 -82 -33 -29 -3 -242 -5 -473 -3 -377 3 -424 5 -447 20 -37 24 -498 873 -498 916 0 22 69 160 232 459 127 236 240 438 251 451 l20 22 492 0 c456 0 493 -1 507 -17z" />
</group>
```

**More rounded corner**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="300dp"
    android:height="300dp"
    android:viewportWidth="300"
    android:viewportHeight="300">

    <path

        android:fillAlpha="0"
        android:strokeColor="#2ed596"
        android:strokeWidth="5"
        android:pathData="M139.4 41.45L141.58 41.45L143.85 41.46L146.23 41.47L148.7 41.49L151.28 41.5L153.96 41.52L197.21 41.77L204.54 45.2L204.95 45.4L205.38 45.62L205.83 45.87L206.3 46.13L206.78 46.42L207.28 46.73L207.8 47.06L208.34 47.42L208.9 47.8L209.48 48.2L210.08 48.63L210.71 49.09L211.36 49.57L212.04 50.08L212.74 50.62L213.46 51.19L214.22 51.79L215 52.42L215.81 53.08L216.65 53.77L217.52 54.49L218.42 55.24L219.35 56.03L220.31 56.85L221.31 57.71L222.34 58.6L223.4 59.52L224.5 60.49L225.64 61.49L226.81 62.52L228.02 63.6L229.27 64.72L230.56 65.87L231.89 67.07L233.25 68.3L234.67 69.58L236.12 70.9L237.61 72.26L239.15 73.66L240.74 75.11L242.53 76.76L244.25 78.35L245.9 79.88L247.48 81.35L249 82.76L250.46 84.11L251.85 85.41L253.18 86.66L254.45 87.86L255.66 89L256.82 90.1L257.92 91.16L258.97 92.17L259.97 93.14L260.92 94.07L261.82 94.96L262.68 95.81L263.49 96.63L264.25 97.41L264.98 98.16L265.67 98.88L266.32 99.57L266.93 100.24L267.5 100.88L268.05 101.49L268.56 102.09L269.04 102.66L269.5 103.22L269.93 103.76L270.33 104.28L270.71 104.79L271.07 105.29L271.41 105.78L271.73 106.26L272.03 106.74L272.32 107.21L272.59 107.67L272.85 108.14L273.11 108.6L273.35 109.07L277.08 116.55L277.08 197.46L272.82 205.43L272.54 205.93L272.26 206.43L271.97 206.93L271.67 207.43L271.36 207.93L271.03 208.43L270.69 208.94L270.33 209.46L269.95 209.98L269.54 210.52L269.12 211.07L268.67 211.63L268.2 212.2L267.7 212.8L267.17 213.41L266.6 214.04L266.01 214.7L265.38 215.38L264.72 216.08L264.01 216.82L263.27 217.58L262.49 218.37L261.67 219.2L260.8 220.06L259.88 220.95L258.92 221.88L257.91 222.86L256.85 223.87L255.74 224.93L254.57 226.03L253.34 227.18L252.06 228.38L250.72 229.62L249.32 230.92L247.85 232.27L246.33 233.67L244.73 235.14L243.07 236.66L241.34 238.24L239.54 239.88L236.76 242.43L234.14 244.84L231.66 247.12L229.33 249.28L227.12 251.3L225.03 253.2L223.05 254.99L221.17 256.66L219.37 258.22L217.66 259.68L216.01 261.03L214.42 262.28L212.87 263.43L211.37 264.5L209.89 265.47L208.43 266.36L206.97 267.18L205.51 267.91L204.04 268.57L202.54 269.16L201.01 269.69L199.43 270.15L197.8 270.56L196.11 270.91L194.34 271.22L192.49 271.47L190.54 271.68L188.49 271.86L186.32 271.99L184.03 272.1L181.6 272.18L179.02 272.23L176.29 272.27L173.39 272.28L170.32 272.29L167.06 272.28L163.61 272.27L159.95 272.26L156.07 272.25L151.96 272.24L147.86 272.25L143.98 272.26L140.31 272.27L136.86 272.28L133.6 272.29L130.53 272.28L127.63 272.27L124.9 272.23L122.33 272.18L119.9 272.1L117.6 271.99L115.43 271.86L113.38 271.68L111.43 271.47L109.58 271.22L107.81 270.91L106.12 270.56L104.49 270.15L102.91 269.69L101.38 269.16L99.89 268.57L98.41 267.91L96.95 267.18L95.5 266.36L94.03 265.47L92.55 264.5L91.05 263.43L89.5 262.28L87.91 261.03L86.26 259.68L84.55 258.22L82.75 256.66L80.87 254.99L78.89 253.2L76.8 251.3L74.6 249.28L72.26 247.12L69.79 244.84L67.16 242.43L64.38 239.88L62.58 238.24L60.85 236.66L59.19 235.14L57.59 233.67L56.07 232.27L54.6 230.92L53.2 229.62L51.86 228.38L50.58 227.18L49.35 226.03L48.19 224.93L47.07 223.87L46.01 222.86L45 221.88L44.04 220.95L43.12 220.06L42.25 219.2L41.43 218.37L40.65 217.58L39.91 216.82L39.2 216.08L38.54 215.38L37.91 214.7L37.32 214.04L36.76 213.41L36.22 212.8L35.72 212.2L35.25 211.63L34.8 211.07L34.38 210.52L33.98 209.98L33.59 209.46L33.23 208.94L32.89 208.43L32.56 207.93L32.25 207.43L31.95 206.93L31.66 206.43L31.38 205.93L31.11 205.43L26.85 197.46L26.85 157L26.85 154.07L26.85 151.28L26.85 148.64L26.85 146.12L26.85 143.74L26.86 141.49L26.86 139.36L26.87 137.35L26.88 135.45L26.9 133.67L26.91 131.98L26.93 130.41L26.96 128.92L26.98 127.53L27.01 126.23L27.05 125.01L27.09 123.88L27.14 122.82L27.19 121.82L27.25 120.9L27.31 120.04L27.38 119.24L27.45 118.49L27.54 117.79L27.63 117.13L27.72 116.52L27.83 115.94L27.94 115.4L28.06 114.88L28.19 114.39L28.33 113.91L28.48 113.46L28.64 113.01L28.81 112.57L28.99 112.13L29.17 111.68L29.37 111.24L29.59 110.78L29.81 110.3L30.04 109.81L30.25 109.39L30.47 108.97L30.7 108.55L30.95 108.12L31.22 107.68L31.5 107.23L31.81 106.78L32.13 106.31L32.48 105.82L32.85 105.33L33.25 104.81L33.67 104.28L34.12 103.74L34.6 103.17L35.11 102.58L35.65 101.97L36.22 101.33L36.82 100.67L37.47 99.98L38.14 99.26L38.86 98.52L39.61 97.74L40.41 96.93L41.24 96.09L42.12 95.21L43.05 94.3L44.01 93.35L45.03 92.36L46.09 91.33L47.2 90.26L48.37 89.14L49.58 87.98L50.85 86.78L52.17 85.53L53.55 84.23L54.98 82.88L56.48 81.47L58.03 80.02L59.64 78.51L61.32 76.95L63.44 74.97L65.47 73.08L67.42 71.27L69.28 69.54L71.07 67.89L72.77 66.32L74.41 64.82L75.97 63.39L77.46 62.04L78.88 60.75L80.24 59.53L81.55 58.37L82.79 57.28L83.98 56.24L85.12 55.27L86.2 54.34L87.25 53.47L88.24 52.65L89.2 51.88L90.12 51.16L91 50.48L91.85 49.84L92.68 49.25L93.47 48.69L94.24 48.16L94.99 47.67L95.72 47.22L96.44 46.79L97.14 46.38L97.84 46.01L98.52 45.65L99.21 45.32L99.89 45L100.57 44.7L101.25 44.41L101.95 44.14L102.65 43.87L103.36 43.62L104.09 43.36L104.84 43.11L105.22 43L105.61 42.89L106.01 42.78L106.43 42.68L106.87 42.58L107.34 42.49L107.82 42.4L108.34 42.31L108.89 42.23L109.47 42.16L110.08 42.09L110.73 42.02L111.42 41.96L112.15 41.9L112.93 41.85L113.76 41.79L114.63 41.75L115.55 41.7L116.53 41.66L117.57 41.63L118.67 41.6L119.82 41.57L121.04 41.54L122.33 41.52L123.69 41.5L125.12 41.48L126.62 41.47L128.2 41.46L129.85 41.45L131.59 41.44L133.41 41.44L135.32 41.44L137.31 41.44L139.4 41.45ZM136.51 43.93L134.36 43.94L132.31 43.96L130.35 43.99L128.49 44.02L126.71 44.05L125.02 44.1L123.41 44.15L121.87 44.21L120.41 44.28L119.01 44.35L117.68 44.44L116.42 44.53L115.21 44.63L114.05 44.74L112.95 44.87L111.9 45L110.88 45.15L109.91 45.3L108.98 45.47L108.08 45.65L107.2 45.84L106.35 46.05L105.53 46.27L104.72 46.5L103.93 46.74L103.14 47L102.37 47.28L101.59 47.56L100.82 47.87L100.04 48.19L99.26 48.52L98.47 48.88L97.66 49.24L97.46 49.35L97.22 49.5L96.94 49.69L96.61 49.92L96.24 50.19L95.82 50.5L95.37 50.85L94.87 51.24L94.34 51.66L93.77 52.12L93.16 52.62L92.52 53.14L91.84 53.7L91.14 54.3L90.39 54.92L89.62 55.57L88.82 56.26L87.99 56.97L87.13 57.71L86.24 58.47L85.33 59.26L84.4 60.07L83.44 60.91L82.46 61.77L81.45 62.65L80.43 63.55L79.39 64.47L78.33 65.41L77.26 66.37L76.17 67.35L75.06 68.34L73.94 69.34L72.81 70.36L71.67 71.39L70.52 72.44L69.36 73.49L68.19 74.56L67.01 75.63L65.83 76.72L64.65 77.81L61.9 80.34L59.29 82.72L56.83 84.98L54.51 87.11L52.32 89.12L50.27 91.03L48.34 92.84L46.53 94.57L44.84 96.21L43.27 97.79L41.8 99.3L40.45 100.76L39.19 102.18L38.04 103.57L36.98 104.93L36.01 106.27L35.12 107.6L34.32 108.94L33.6 110.29L32.95 111.66L32.38 113.06L31.87 114.49L31.42 115.97L31.03 117.51L30.69 119.11L30.41 120.79L30.17 122.55L29.98 124.4L29.82 126.35L29.7 128.41L29.61 130.59L29.55 132.89L29.5 135.33L29.48 137.92L29.47 140.66L29.48 143.57L29.48 146.65L29.49 149.91L29.5 153.36L29.51 157L29.5 160.6L29.49 163.99L29.48 167.2L29.47 170.22L29.46 173.07L29.47 175.76L29.49 178.3L29.53 180.69L29.59 182.95L29.69 185.08L29.81 187.1L29.96 189.01L30.16 190.82L30.4 192.54L30.69 194.18L31.04 195.76L31.44 197.27L31.9 198.73L32.42 200.14L33.02 201.52L33.69 202.88L34.43 204.22L35.26 205.56L36.18 206.89L37.18 208.24L38.28 209.62L39.48 211.02L40.78 212.46L42.19 213.95L43.71 215.5L45.35 217.12L47.11 218.81L48.99 220.59L51 222.46L53.14 224.44L55.42 226.53L57.83 228.74L60.4 231.08L63.11 233.57L65.98 236.2L68.79 238.81L71.44 241.27L73.94 243.6L76.3 245.79L78.52 247.86L80.63 249.8L82.62 251.62L84.52 253.33L86.32 254.92L88.04 256.4L89.69 257.78L91.28 259.06L92.82 260.23L94.32 261.32L95.79 262.31L97.24 263.22L98.68 264.05L100.12 264.79L101.56 265.47L103.03 266.07L104.53 266.6L106.06 267.07L107.65 267.49L109.29 267.84L111.01 268.15L112.81 268.41L114.69 268.62L116.68 268.8L118.77 268.94L120.99 269.04L123.33 269.12L125.82 269.17L128.46 269.21L131.25 269.22L134.22 269.22L137.37 269.22L140.7 269.21L144.24 269.19L147.99 269.18L151.96 269.18L155.93 269.18L159.68 269.19L163.22 269.21L166.55 269.22L169.7 269.22L172.67 269.22L175.47 269.21L178.1 269.17L180.59 269.12L182.93 269.04L185.15 268.94L187.25 268.8L189.23 268.62L191.12 268.41L192.91 268.15L194.63 267.84L196.27 267.49L197.86 267.07L199.4 266.6L200.89 266.07L202.36 265.47L203.81 264.79L205.24 264.05L206.68 263.22L208.13 262.31L209.6 261.32L211.1 260.23L212.64 259.06L214.23 257.78L215.88 256.4L217.6 254.92L219.41 253.33L221.3 251.62L223.29 249.8L225.4 247.86L227.63 245.79L229.98 243.6L232.48 241.27L235.13 238.81L237.94 236.2L240.81 233.57L243.52 231.08L246.09 228.74L248.51 226.53L250.78 224.44L252.93 222.46L254.93 220.59L256.81 218.81L258.57 217.12L260.21 215.5L261.73 213.95L263.14 212.46L264.44 211.02L265.64 209.62L266.74 208.24L267.74 206.89L268.66 205.56L269.49 204.22L270.23 202.88L270.9 201.52L271.5 200.14L272.02 198.73L272.48 197.27L272.88 195.76L273.23 194.18L273.52 192.54L273.76 190.82L273.96 189.01L274.11 187.1L274.24 185.08L274.33 182.95L274.39 180.69L274.43 178.3L274.45 175.76L274.46 173.07L274.45 170.22L274.44 167.2L274.43 163.99L274.42 160.6L274.41 157L274.42 153.35L274.43 149.89L274.44 146.63L274.45 143.54L274.45 140.63L274.44 137.89L274.41 135.3L274.37 132.85L274.3 130.54L274.21 128.36L274.08 126.3L273.92 124.35L273.73 122.5L273.48 120.74L273.19 119.06L272.85 117.45L272.45 115.91L272 114.43L271.47 112.99L270.89 111.58L270.23 110.21L269.49 108.85L268.67 107.5L267.77 106.15L266.78 104.8L265.7 103.42L264.53 102.02L263.25 100.58L261.87 99.1L260.38 97.56L258.77 95.96L257.05 94.29L255.21 92.53L253.25 90.69L251.15 88.74L248.93 86.69L246.56 84.51L244.06 82.21L241.41 79.78L238.61 77.2L236.67 75.41L234.8 73.69L233.02 72.06L231.32 70.5L229.69 69.01L228.14 67.59L226.65 66.24L225.24 64.95L223.89 63.73L222.6 62.57L221.38 61.48L220.21 60.44L219.1 59.45L218.04 58.53L217.03 57.65L216.07 56.83L215.16 56.05L214.29 55.32L213.46 54.64L212.67 54L211.92 53.39L211.2 52.83L210.51 52.31L209.85 51.82L209.22 51.36L208.61 50.94L208.02 50.54L207.45 50.17L206.9 49.83L206.36 49.51L205.83 49.21L205.31 48.93L204.8 48.67L204.3 48.42L203.79 48.19L203.29 47.97L202.78 47.76L202.26 47.55L201.74 47.35L201.21 47.16L200.64 46.95L200.09 46.76L199.55 46.57L199.03 46.39L198.51 46.22L197.99 46.06L197.47 45.91L196.95 45.77L196.42 45.63L195.88 45.51L195.32 45.39L194.73 45.27L194.13 45.17L193.5 45.07L192.83 44.98L192.13 44.89L191.39 44.81L190.61 44.74L189.78 44.67L188.9 44.6L187.96 44.54L186.96 44.49L185.91 44.44L184.78 44.39L183.59 44.35L182.32 44.31L180.97 44.27L179.54 44.24L178.03 44.21L176.43 44.18L174.73 44.15L172.94 44.13L171.04 44.11L169.04 44.08L166.93 44.06L164.71 44.05L162.37 44.03L159.91 44.01L157.33 43.99L154.62 43.97L151.68 43.96L148.86 43.94L146.17 43.93L143.59 43.93L141.12 43.92L138.76 43.93L136.51 43.93Z" />
</vector>
```

Comment: will you rotate this design. top and bottom corner should come left and right

Comment: awesome. i want only stroke color green. fill color should transparent. how to do that

Comment: have you image as you want?

Comment: yes. its correct. i need stroke color should green.. fill color should transparent

Comment: u r awesome..i need more round in corner.. what to do

Comment: now it becomes octagonal. i want hexagon only. i need slight more round

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this one.

I've painted in Sketch

with 25 corner radius.

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="250"
    android:viewportHeight="235">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#00000000"
        android:fillType="evenOdd"
        android:pathData="M239.887,125.879C242.736,120.656 242.736,114.344 239.887,109.121L189.522,16.774C186.455,11.152 180.563,7.654 174.158,7.654L75.842,7.654C69.437,7.654 63.545,11.152 60.478,16.774L10.113,109.121C7.264,114.344 7.264,120.656 10.113,125.879L60.478,218.226C63.545,223.848 69.437,227.346 75.842,227.346L174.158,227.346C180.563,227.346 186.455,223.848 189.522,218.226L239.887,125.879Z"
        android:strokeWidth="15"
        android:strokeColor="#008000" />
</vector>
```

with 30:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="248"
    android:viewportHeight="235">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#00000000"
        android:fillType="evenOdd"
        android:pathData="M237.581,128.273C241.244,121.558 241.244,113.442 237.581,106.727L189.943,19.38C186.001,12.151 178.424,7.654 170.19,7.654L77.81,7.654C69.576,7.654 61.999,12.151 58.057,19.38L10.419,106.727C6.756,113.442 6.756,121.558 10.419,128.273L58.057,215.62C61.999,222.849 69.576,227.346 77.81,227.346L170.19,227.346C178.424,227.346 186.001,222.849 189.943,215.62L237.581,128.273Z"
        android:strokeWidth="15"
        android:strokeColor="#008000" />
</vector>
```

With 40:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="246"
    android:viewportHeight="235">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#00000000"
        android:fillType="evenOdd"
        android:pathData="M233.97,133.061C239.26,123.362 239.26,111.638 233.97,101.939L191.786,24.592C186.091,14.15 175.147,7.654 163.253,7.654L82.747,7.654C70.853,7.654 59.909,14.15 54.214,24.592L12.03,101.939C6.74,111.638 6.74,123.362 12.03,133.061L54.214,210.408C59.909,220.85 70.853,227.346 82.747,227.346L163.253,227.346C175.147,227.346 186.091,220.85 191.786,210.408L233.97,133.061Z"
        android:strokeWidth="15"
        android:strokeColor="#008000" />
</vector>
```

With 50:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="244"
    android:viewportHeight="235">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#00000000"
        android:fillType="evenOdd"
        android:pathData="M230.359,137.849C237.277,125.165 237.277,109.835 230.359,97.151L193.628,29.804C186.181,16.15 171.87,7.654 156.317,7.654L87.683,7.654C72.13,7.654 57.819,16.15 50.372,29.804L13.641,97.151C6.723,109.835 6.723,125.165 13.641,137.849L50.372,205.196C57.819,218.85 72.13,227.346 87.683,227.346L156.317,227.346C171.87,227.346 186.181,218.85 193.628,205.196L230.359,137.849Z"
        android:strokeWidth="15"
        android:strokeColor="#008000" />
</vector>
```

Comment: if i want more rounded corner. what i have to do

Comment: when i set it as text view background shows little blur

Comment: Which parameters of textview do you set? `layout_width`, `layout_height`, `background` or `drawableStart` ?

Comment: i set it as background

Comment: Understood. What are the values of `layout_width` and `layout_height ` ?

Comment: layout_width =match_parent, layout_height =80dp